# Database UPDATE Query do not work VB.Net

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, sql-update

My Queries to Insert and select works fine. But the update doesn't work. There is no error but the database would not be updated.
Here's the code
 Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\TMJ\Documents\Database1.accdb")
        Dim command As OleDbCommand

```
    connection.Open()
    command = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Students SET first_name=@fname,middle_name=@mname,last_name=@lname,add_line1=@add1,add_line2=@add2,add_line3=@add3,dob=@bd,gender=@gen,f_first_name=@fname1,f_middle_name=@fname2,f_last_name=@fname3,f_occupation=@fjob,m_first_name=@mname1,m_middle_name=@mname2,m_last_name=@mname3,m_occupation=@mjob,date_enrolled=@de,class=@clas,subject1=@sub1,subject2=@sub2,subject3=@sub3,additional_details=@ad WHERE Admission_no=@adno; ", connection)
    command.Parameters.Add("@adno", OleDbType.Integer).Value = txt_adno.Text
    command.Parameters.Add("@fname", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txt_stdname1.Text
    command.Parameters.Add("@mname", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txt_stdname2.Text
    command.Parameters.Add("@lname", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txt_stdname3.Text
    command.Parameters.Add("@add1", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txt_address1.Text
    command.Parameters.Add("@add2", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txt_address2.Text
    command.Parameters.Add("@add3", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txt_address3.Text
    command.Parameters.Add("@bd", OleDbType.Date).Value = date_dob.Value
    command.Parameters.Add("@gen", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = cmb_gender.Text
    command.Parameters.Add("@fname1", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txt_FName1.Text
    command.Parameters.Add("@fname2", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txt_FName2.Text
    command.Parameters.Add("@fname3", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txt_FName3.Text
    command.Parameters.Add("@fjob", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txt_FOccupation.Text
    command.Parameters.Add("@mname1", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txt_MName1.Text
    command.Parameters.Add("@mname2", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txt_MName2.Text
    command.Parameters.Add("@mname3", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txt_MName3.Text
    command.Parameters.Add("mjob", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txt_MOccupation.Text
    command.Parameters.Add("@de", OleDbType.Date).Value = dtpDateEnrolled.Value
    command.Parameters.Add("@clas", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = cmbclass.Text
    command.Parameters.Add("@sub1", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = cmbsubject1.Text
    command.Parameters.Add("@sub2", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = cmbsubject2.Text
    command.Parameters.Add("@sub3", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = cmbsubject3.Text
    command.Parameters.Add("@ad", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtlastSchool.Text


    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    connection.Close()
```

Comment: Try an update with 1 column and the where clause. If that works, start adding columns and parameters until something breaks. Is 'mjob' missing an '@' ? Do you need that semi-colon at the end?

Comment: Using OleDB you must provide the Parameter values in the same exact order as they appear in the SQL.  You might also want to read up on normalization.

Comment: These problems are almost always because the `WHERE` clause filters out what you think is going to be updated. You do not validate what is in `txt_adno` and you are assigning a string value to an integer type parameter.